# Excel. Worksheet Change to Worksheet Calculate

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that runs perfectly on "Worksheet_Change" event.

The value in cell "A1" changes frequently from a live feed.

I need help to adapt the code from this event to work with "Worksheet_Calculate" event.

Every time Cell value A1 changes, automatically the Old value must be shown in A2.

```
A1    New Value
A2    Old Value
```

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim NewValue, OldValue
    If Target.Address <> "$A$1" Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Target
        NewValue = .Value
        Application.Undo
        OldValue = .Value
        .Value = NewValue
    End With
    Range("a2").Value = OldValue
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one sheet place this code in the Sheet module (initial Old value will be empty)

```
Option Explicit

Private oldVal As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    updateOldValue Me.Range("A1")
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    updateOldValue Target
End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Public Sub updateOldValue(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            If .Address = "$A$1" Then
                .Offset(1, 0) = oldVal
                oldVal = .Value2
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

.

For multiple sheets, place this code in a new VBA module, and call it the same way:

`updateOldValue Me.Range("A1")` or `updateOldValue Target`:

---

```
Option Explicit

Private oldVal As String

Public Sub updateOldValue(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            If .Address = "$A$1" Then
                .Offset(1, 0) = oldVal
                oldVal = .Value2
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```